# Diagonal slash across page

Tags: css, svg

I'm looking for suggestions on the best way to achieve a diagonal slash across a page which will sit behind the main content area.

I'd like to achieve this without images or additional markup and be able to control the angle of the slash which would be retained if the browser width changed.

I was originally thinking the `:after` pseudo selector could be used for this, though perhaps SVG would be a better option?

Rough design of slash in light gray:

[image]

Comment: What sort of browser support do you need?

Comment: Down to IE8 would be ideal, though not critical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using some borders in css3 here's a good example: http://www.cssportal.com/css3-shapes/.
See "Triangle Bottom Left".

Comment: Yup this was my original thought, used on a pseudo selector. Most likely the best way, just wanted to see if there were any more interesting solutions!

Comment: I bet there are more interesting solutions with canvas,JavaScript,etc ...but why complicate things?

Comment: Well exactly, which is why I say it's most likely the best solution. I'll go with this unless there's any alternative method that's a better solution.

Comment: Would suggest this as well.. SVG would be the other good solution (as your guessed), but a css triangle is probably better.

Comment: One restriction of this seems to be that it requires a fixed width/height. Ideally I'd like this to always be the full height of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

check out this JSFiddle:

> http://jsfiddle.net/anzhA/

Or you some other example:

> http://jsfiddle.net/anzhA/1/

The trick is with css borders and width/height set to 0:

```
border-width: 0 500px 500px 0;
border-color: transparent white transparent transparent;
border-style: solid;
height:0;
width:0;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
```

This will show just the bottom-right shape of the border structure. It is triangle.

### EXAMPLE

[image: CSS TRIANGLES]

> First, normal CSS border 2 colors.

> Second, if you replace the second color to transparent and set `width/height` of the element to 0, and remove bottom and left border, you will get result

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the CSS3 borders method, see first answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
      rgba(232, 232, 232, 1),
      rgba(135, 60, 255, 0) 0%
    ),
    -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(231, 229, 229, 0.9) 55%, rgba(229,230,216,1)
          0%);
```